# iPhone special character ns url post

Tags: iphone

I am working in iPhone. I am using php on server side.
I want to send comments. I am writing my code like this:

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"url" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableString *tempUrl=[tmpDic valueForKey:@"url1"];  
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CC/postcomment",tempUrl];

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"placeId=%d&user_name=%@&comment=%@&userId=%d",uPlaceId,displayName,[self urlEncodeValue:message],[u.userId intValue]];

NSLog(@"%@",post);     

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                      allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request   setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

But when i write some special character in my comment string like as # $ % ^ then it creates problem in sending comments.

for this i used encoding of my comment. this is function for encoding :

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str {
    NSString *result = (NSString *) 
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("?=&+˜!@#$%ˆ&*()_+|\\?'/.>,<;:\"\\'"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Its working fine. but still creating problem when i want to send **** backward slash in comment.
Because this following query and generating:

```
insert into place_comments(placeId,comment_datetime,user_name,comment,userId) values('15','2011-02-01','sharmagunjan','\','199') ;
```

In this query this `\` is creating problem in query.
Please suggest me what should i do for this.

Comment: Any chance you could sort out the question formatting?

Comment: the problem is at the server side i guess where u r inserting the value in the db... for sql operation i suggest you to use "\\\"